# Python - Чтение из файла и просто список?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
f=open('data.txt',"r")
f=(f.read().split())
#f='a3b4c2e10b1'
print(f)
f=list(f)
cf=list('0123456789')
flett=[]
fdig=[]
for i in range (len(f)): 
    if f[i] not in cf:
        flett.append(f[i])
        k=i+1
        fdigit=f[i+1]
        if k==(len(f)-1):
            k=len(f)-1
            fdig.append(fdigit) 
            break
        else:
            k=k+1
        while f[k] in cf:
            fdigit=fdigit+f[k] 
            if k==(len(f)-1):
                k=(len(f)-1)
                break
            else:
              k=k+1    
        fdig.append(fdigit)
strout=""
for i in range  (len(flett)):
    strout=strout+flett[i]*int(fdig[i])
print (strout)
```

Этот вариант дает ошибку:

IndexError: list index out of range on line 13 in main.py(строка fdigit=f[i+1])

А без чтения из файла:

```
f=list('a3b4c2e10b1')
cf=list('0123456789')
flett=[]
fdig=[]
for i in range (len(f)): 
    if f[i] not in cf:
        flett.append(f[i])
        k=i+1
        fdigit=f[i+1]
        if k==(len(f)-1):
            k=len(f)-1
            fdig.append(fdigit) 
            break
        else:
            k=k+1
        while f[k] in cf:
            fdigit=fdigit+f[k] 
            if k==(len(f)-1):
                k=(len(f)-1)
                break
            else:
              k=k+1    
        fdig.append(fdigit) 
print (fdig)
```

ошибки нет.
Задача разделить буквы и числа (строка такая буква затем число) используя только простые методы(других кагбы не знаем). Описание работы программы:
(**cf вспомогательный список для выделения цифр из списка f)**

1. читаем сроку из файла
2. делаем из нее список
3. цикл (**for**) перебор элементов получившегося сиска

   - первое условие (**if f[i] not in cf:**)проверка вляется ли элемент списка f буквой список flett
   - цикл (**while**) проверка является ли элемент списка f цифрой (содержится в списке cf) прибавление цифр если число многоразрядное переменная fdigit ( **while f[k] in cf:
         fdigit=fdigit+f[k]** )
   - if вместе с break проверка окончания индекса списка.
     Делал код в pythontutor с пошаговым режимом там нет возможности считать файл
     поэтому задал готовую строку код нормально работал.

Comment: `f=list(open("data.txt","w"))` - это вы так получаете список строк из файла?

Comment: А почему Вы открываете файл с `"w"` параметром записи?

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in range (len(f)):
```

Это значит что `i+1` в строке

```
fdigit=f[i+1]
```

может быть *"out of range"* индексом (когда `break` не встречается вовремя).

Поэтому вашей программе нужна правка в любом случае - независимо от способа заполнения переменной `f`.

Только после этого будет смысл заниматься различными результатами этих двух подходов - если после правки хоть какой-то будет.

Comment: но когда f готовый список всё работает.

Comment: @Fyt просто повезло. В любом случае описанную в ответе проблему нужно обязательно исправить

Comment: Верно, плюс вам. Я немного поправил формулировки. :)

Answer (score 2):

Как минимум, вы некорректно открываете файл - на запись,  с параметром `w`. 
Таким образом содержимое файла перезаписывается.
Проверьте, наверняка ваш `data.txt` давно пуст.

Вот неплохой способ получить список строк из файла:

```
with open('question.md') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
```

А так то же самое, но без `\n` (символов переноса строки) в конце каждой строки:

```
with open('question.md') as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
```

Наконец, можно не получать список сразу, а итерировать элементы:

```
with open('question.md') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться менеджером контекста и открыть файл для чтения:

```
>>> with open("test.txt", "r") as f:  # ['1\n', '1\n', '1\n', '1\n']
...   a = f.read().splitlines()
... 
>>> a
['1', '1', '1', '1']
```

В ответах Вам написали почему так происходит, так как Вы делаете, делать не надо, надо либо обернуть присваивание элемента, которого может не существовать обработкой исключенией:

```
try:
    fdigit = f[i+1]
except IndexError:
    break
```

Либо переписать код и сделать проверку `if k <= (len(f)-1): ...` перед присваиванием.

И после открытия файло его нужно закрывать.

P.S. извините, но в Вашем коде сам черт ногу сломит, напишите условие, чего Вы хотите добиться, мы поможем сделать красиво, я сомневаюсь, что есть необходимость использовать `while` цикл в `for`, а также контроль шага как это реализованно...

Comment: вместо `a = [i.replace('\n', '') for i in f]` можно `f.read().splitlines()`

Comment: поправил вопрос.

Comment: @Fyt поправил ответ.